# converting separate strings into datetime python

Tags: python, datetime, sqlite

I am writing code that will add staff shifts into a shift schedule. the part I am trying to get to work is one that adds shifts in that recur every week (ie work every Monday at 5). I thought I had a good way of doing it until I started getting error messages regarding the datatype. I am new to the datetime module so I apologise if there is a simple explanation

here is the relevant part of my code:

```
def addWeekly(STAFFID,SDAY,SMONTH,SYEAR,STARTTIME,ENDTIME):
    DATE = datetime.date(SYEAR, SMONTH, SDAY)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    count = 0

    for records in cursor:
        count += 1
    SHIFTID = count

    for i in range(100):
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO SHIFT VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',
            (SHIFTID,STAFFID,DATE,STARTTIME,ENDTIME))
        DATE += timedelta(days=7)
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/360491/Documents/Coursework/Prototypes/calendar fix.py", line 36, in <module>
addWeekly(STAFFID,SDAY,SMONTH,SYEAR,STARTTIME,ENDTIME)
  File "C:/Users/360491/Documents/Coursework/Prototypes/calendar fix.py", line 16, in addWeekly
DATE = datetime.date(SYEAR, SMONTH, SDAY)
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'
```

i have tried using integers.
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure `SYEAR, SMONTH, SDAY` are integers?

Comment: Can you show your imports?

Comment: When you get the answer you need on SO you should, please, mark it 'accepted'. With sufficient reputation you can start up-voting answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing `datetime.datetime`?

Try just using `import datetime`